# What command prints a string as "big ascii text art" in bash?

Tags: bash, scripting, ascii

I'm looking for a program that turns an ASCII string into something like the "ascii art" below:

```
    .-"^`\                                        /`^"-.
  .'   ___\                                      /___   `.
 /    /.---.                                    .---.\    \
|    //     '-.  ___________________________ .-'     \\    |
|   ;|         \/--------------------------//         |;   |
\   ||       |\_)          Red Hat         (_/|       ||   /
 \  | \  . \ ;  |     Enterprise Linux     || ; / .  / |  /
  '\_\ \\ \ \ \ |                          ||/ / / // /_/'
        \\ \ \ \|    Server Release 5.3    |/ / / //
         `'-\_\_\     Codename Tikanga     /_/_/-'`
                '--------------------------'
```

I don't have a matching example but I would like the string be turned into some multi line text, like:

```
 __    __
/  |  /  |
|  |  |  |
|  |--|  |
|  |--|  |
|  |  |  | 
|_/   |_/
```

for the letter `H` and so on... I would like to use this to show certain warning messages, for example when the user is about to run a script that will delete the production database and so on...

Thanks!

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
$ figlet you want figlet
                                         _      __ _       _      _   
 _   _  ___  _   _  __      ____ _ _ __ | |_   / _(_) __ _| | ___| |_ 
| | | |/ _ \| | | | \ \ /\ / / _` | '_ \| __| | |_| |/ _` | |/ _ \ __|
| |_| | (_) | |_| |  \ V  V / (_| | | | | |_  |  _| | (_| | |  __/ |_ 
 \__, |\___/ \__,_|   \_/\_/ \__,_|_| |_|\__| |_| |_|\__, |_|\___|\__|
 |___/                                               |___/
```

Comment: +1 - Oh, how I love figlet. Proportional fonts SUCK...

Comment: There's a web front end for figlet at:

http://www.bigtext.org/

Comment: bigtext.org seems to be no more

Comment: this works on osx using homebrew too! `brew install figlet`

Comment: i purposely logged in just to upvote this!!!!!

Answer (score 17):

There's also the old-school command "banner".  It is crude but effective.

```
$ banner banner

######      #     #     #  #     #  #######  ######
#     #    # #    ##    #  ##    #  #        #     #
#     #   #   #   # #   #  # #   #  #        #     #
######   #     #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #####    ######
#     #  #######  #   # #  #   # #  #        #   #
#     #  #     #  #    ##  #    ##  #        #    #
######   #     #  #     #  #     #  #######  #     #
```

A bit of googling showed me that rpmfind knows where to find it (although rpmfind appears to be having problems themselves these days...)

Answer (score 5):

Figlet can do that, and is in the Ubuntu Repos `sudo apt-get install figlet`:

["Using Figlet to Spice Up your Scripts"](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-using-figlet-spice-your-scripts) is a recent Linux Journal Article on the Topic.

Comment: Too sloooow :-)

Comment: Maybe just too small?

Answer (score 5):

[Toilet](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/toilet) is even better. ;) I always used it as code banner for my applications

```
  ▞▀▖         ▐     ▜  ▙▗▌      ▗▐         
  ▌  ▙▀▖▌ ▌▞▀▘▜▀ ▝▀▖▐  ▌▘▌▞▀▖▛▀▖▄▜▀ ▞▀▖▙▀▖ 
  ▌ ▖▌  ▚▄▌▝▀▖▐ ▖▞▀▌▐  ▌ ▌▌ ▌▌ ▌▐▐ ▖▌ ▌▌   
  ▝▀ ▘  ▗▄▘▀▀  ▀ ▝▀▘ ▘ ▘ ▘▝▀ ▘ ▘▀▘▀ ▝▀ ▘
```

There's a pretty good write-up of how to use it over on cyberciti.biz, titled: [UNIX / Linux: Display Large Colourful Text Banner On Screen](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-large-colorful-text-banner-on-screen/)

Answer (score 5):

`cowsay`

```
$ cowsay cowsay makes banners
 ______________________
< cowsay makes banners >
 ----------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||

$ cowsay -f tux cowsay is customisable
 ________________________
< cowsay is customisable >
 ------------------------
   \
    \
        .--.
       |o_o |
       |:_/ |
      //   \ \
     (|     | )
    /'\_   _/`\
    \___)=(___/
```

`cowsay` is amusingly '90s and provides a bunch of options for tweaking the cow's appearance. Read `man cowsay`.

It's still packaged for Ubuntu and Debian: `sudo apt install cowsay`

Comment: If you would like the man page to be read by a cow, check `man cowsay | cowsay`

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that your first example was created using [boxes](http://boxes.thomasjensen.com/).